# TypeError:Invalid arguement, not a string or column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do some source to target testing in pyspark. First part I am trying to do is a count of columns using a Lean Six Sigma method making sure there are less than 3/1000000 discrepancies in the columns. When I run this though, the if statement throws a:

TypeError: Invalid arguement, not a string or column: -276244 of type <class 'int'>. For columns literals, use 'lit', 'array','struct' or 'create_map' function.

Could anyone help?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

good_fields = []
bad_fields = {}
count_issues = {}


columns = list(spark.sql('show columns from tu_historical').toPandas()['col_name'])

for col in columns: 
   print(col)
   df = spark.sql(f'select pid,fnum,{col} from historical_clean')
   df1 = spark.sql(f'select pid,fnum,{col} from historical1')
   
   #count issue testing
   if abs(df1.count()-df.count()) > df1.count()*.000003:
      count_issues[col] = df1.count()-df.count()

   test_df = df.join(df1,(df.num == df1.file) & (df1.pid == df.pid),'left').filter(df1[col]!=df[col])
```

Comment: can you post the output of `spark.sql('select * from tu_historical limit 0').columns`

Comment: Out[27]: ['PID',                     
'POWNER',
'SID',
'SOWNER',
'DATE',
'score04',
'score33s',
There are a bunch more columns but they are all mostly the same, all of the column names appear to be coming in as normal using both methods.

Comment: I think you must have a column name that's getting misinterpreted.  if you limit your columns to the first 5 columns what happens? If you limit your columns to the next 5 columns what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `columns` has a funky value in it.

You may want to use this to get the columns names:

```
columns = spark.sql('select * from tu_historical limit 0').columns
```

Comment: Tried that, still throwing the same error.